# Rehydrate a query in apollo in client after server side rendering

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I am rendering a page from server side using apollo . Its loading perfectly from backend. But when it is loaded in frontend , a call to graphql api is again made. I want to prevent that .

```html
const client = new ApolloClient({
 cache: new InMemoryCache({
  cacheRedirects: {
   Query: {
    eventQuery: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => getCacheKey({ __typename: 'Event', id: args.id }),
   },
  },
 }).restore(window.__APOLLO_STATE__),
 link: new HttpLink({
  credentials: 'include',
  uri: `/graphql`,
  ssrForceFetchDelay: 2000,
 }),
});
```

I have tried to use InMemoryCache to rehydrate.